# PostrgreSql database write/read statistics

Tags: postgresql

Does someone know how much more write operations overload the PostgreSQL database than read operations? Is it measurable in the general case?

Comment: This is not answerable in general, it depends very much on your hardware, your concurrency level, and what it is that is being read and written.  And your PostgreSQL version and durability settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [`pg_stat_all_tables`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ALL-TABLES-VIEW) you will find this information:

- `seq_tup_read` and `ind_tup_fetch` will tell you how many rows were read with sequential and index scans
- `n_tup_ins`, `n_tup_upd` and `n_tup_del` will tell you how many rows were modified

From that you should be able to compute the desired information.